# Log not found error in node js while creating react app

Tags: node.js

After installing node js msi file in windows 10 it is showing installed but when i m trying to make a react project it is giving error below:
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\JOINT INFOTECH\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\JOINT INFOTECH\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\JOINT INFOTECH\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-21T10_39_25_501Z-debug-0.log

Guys help me if anyone have faced this issue also.[error snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NC3P.png)

I want to create react app without ant error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.